# HTML.innerHTML vs Jquery.html() - Javascript execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss

Ref: [html() vs innerHTML jquery/javascript & XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318581/html-vs-innerhtml-jquery-javascript-xss-attacks)

From this, I can infer that, Jquery extracts the `<script>` tags and execute separately in DOM, it doesn't appear in DOM.

Consider the following HTML code:

a = `<iframe><iframe //><script>alert(1)</script>`

b = `<iframe><iframe> //<script>alert(1)</script>`

As of the code in `a`, `body.innerHTML = a;` doesn't execute the script, but `$("body").html(a);` does.

Why? Jquery's `.html()` execute the content after `//` but `.innerHTML =` doesn't?

If it is so, why `b` inside either `.innerHTML =` or `.html()` doesn't get executed?

**Update:** For a demo, open up console, and execute this:

1. `document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe><iframe //><script>alert(1)</script>"`
2. `$("body").html("<iframe><iframe //><script>alert(1)</script>");`

1 will not execute alert(), but 2 will. Replace the HTML values with `b`. Neither will get executed.

**Update 2:** From what I can determine that the HTML code will get executed in Jquery's `body()` but not in `.innerHTML=`?

Comment: `//` is not an html comment...they look like `<!--  -->`

Comment: And closing tag is also wrong

Comment: @BharatPatidar I know it's wrong. But, for this malformed HTML code, why this difference between .innerHTML() and Jquery's .html()?

Comment: [Difference between innerHTML and .html() from jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390542/difference-between-innerhtml-and-html-from-jquery)

Comment: @prasad That doesn't answer the second part. Why `b` and `c` doesn't execute with .html()?

Comment: yes..i don't give any answer for you.just comment with related topics of your question.

Comment: but innerHTML - not a function

Comment: `b` and `c` don't execute with innerHTML either

Comment: @mrid I meant to ask, why `b` and `c` doesn't execute when `a` executes with `.html()`?

Comment: you still should fix your markup. even if the behavior doesn't change by fixing it. a valid markup is important.

Comment: Test c again, it's executing in my test

Comment: @TommySchmidt What do you mean by a markup?

Comment: In case b)  <iframe><iframe> //<script>alert(1)</script> , the // are outside any tag, try putting them inside a tag like <div><iframe><iframe> //<script>alert(1)</script> </div> and then it will execute too

Comment: html = hypertext markup language. so i mean your html.

Comment: @TommySchmidt I get that. I understand this markup is invalid. I just want to know why this different behaviour with `.html()`.

Comment: this could be the reason why the behavior is different. i dont know exactly how jquerry handles that string. maybe it is parsing it when it is inserted and the markup error is causing your issue. normally i would test it before posting such a comment but i am on my phone right now. so maybe you should try that out. i could be totally wrong tho.

Comment: @Netham I have removed `c` now. Some error in my console due to XSS filters I use, seems `c` executes in .html(). And, `b` **doesn't** seem to execute when put inside `<div></div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If go a bit deeper in jQuery source code, we can find [`html`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation.js#L400) method.

In this method exist next [line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation.js#L434)

```
this.empty().append( value );
```

If now go to [`append`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation.js#L339), we can find next

```
append: function() {
    return domManip( this, arguments, function( elem ) {
        if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 || this.nodeType === 9 ) {
            var target = manipulationTarget( this, elem );
            target.appendChild( elem );
        }
    } );
}
```

So, now find [`domManip`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation.js#L125). Inside this function from html-string builded fragmen, and if fragment have script tag execute [next code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation.js#L184)

```
DOMEval( node.textContent.replace( rcleanScript, "" ), doc );
```

Where [DOMEval](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/core/DOMEval.js)

```
function DOMEval( code, doc ) {
    doc = doc || document;

    var script = doc.createElement( "script" );

    script.text = code;
    doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
}
```

So, at least, we find place where execute scripts.

---

So, why in some case `html` run script and otherwise not?

This depends on input string and what return [`buildFragment` function](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation/buildFragment.js#L14).

Inside `buildFragment` we can found [next line](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation/buildFragment.js#L44)

```
tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + jQuery.htmlPrefilter( elem ) + wrap[ 2 ];
```

where `elem` is input string, and [`jQuery.htmlPrefilter`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation.js#L237) is next function

```
htmlPrefilter: function( html ) {
    return html.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" );
}
```

so, input string just replaced with some [regular exporession `rxhtmlTag`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/manipulation.js#L36).

```
rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([a-z][^\/\0>\x20\t\r\n\f]*)[^>]*)\/>/gi,
```

So, just try this for checking string:

```js
console.log(jQuery.htmlPrefilter("<iframe><iframe //><script>alert(1)</" + "script>"));
console.log(jQuery.htmlPrefilter("<iframe><iframe> // <script>alert(1)</" + "script>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So, in first case as result was

```
<iframe><iframe /></iframe><script>alert(1)</script>
```

And after insert it as innerHTML in `tmp` div, inside div create **two** elements: iframe and script. So after this script available for finding and executing

In second case:

```
<iframe><iframe> // <script>alert(1)</script>
```

String not changed, and after insert it as innerHTML in `tmp` div, inside div create just one iframe element with encoded content. That's why in this case script not execute.

Comment: Although interesting, this is also stated in the documentation quite clearly: _By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute code. This can occur by injection of script tags or use of HTML attributes that execute code (for example, <img onload="">)_

Comment: it answers why it executes the a, but still hasn't answer the OP's real question, why `$("body").html("<iframe><iframe><script>alert(1)</script>");` doesn't execute the alert?

Comment: @elfan, i get next error for this code _Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token_

Comment: @Grundy, me too, I don't know why, but when I retyped it, it doesn't have syntax error anymore

Comment: I cannot edit my comment the second time. The OP's real question is, why `$("body").html("<iframe><iframe>//<script>alert(1)</script>");` doesn't execute the script?

Comment: @elfan, i found answer in this line: `tmp.innerHTML = wrap[ 1 ] + elem.replace( rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>" ) + wrap[ 2 ];` in one case replace wrap all in `iframe` tag, and script and other tags inside iframe encoded, and in other case, in iframe just `<iframe //>` and script append as is, so it available next for finding and executing

Comment: @elfan, i'm update answer. In you answer you quite right but not think about preprocess input html string

Comment: yes, you're right, and it made me more sure about my answer. In `rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([\w:-]+)[^>]*)\/>/gi,` it says that any other tag with `<tag/>` will be considered as `<tag></tag>` just like `<br />`, `<img />`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think here what's happened

```
<iframe>//<script>alert(1)</script>
```

is not executed because `//<script>alert(1)</script>` is considered as the contents of `<iframe>` tag (that is not closed yet). As we know, the contents of the iframe gets ignored (it is only processed by browsers that don't support iframe).

While

```
<iframe//><script>alert(1)</script>
```

is executed because `<iframe//>` is considered as `<iframe />` which may be interpreted as finished/closed tag just like `<br />` (at least in Chrome, FF, Edge, and IE). Now that the `iframe` element is finished/completed, the next element (`<script>alert(1)</alert>`) gets processed.

Comment: I am more sure of my answer, after seeing the inner working of jquery code as shown in the asnwer by @Grundy, see my comment below it.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see first what gets executed, apart from what you mentioned

```
$("body").html("<iframe//> <script>alert(1)</script>");
$("body").html("<iframe//> // <script>alert(1)</script>");
$("body").html("<iframe><iframe//> <script>alert(1)</script>");
 $("body").html("<iframe><iframe><iframe><iframe//> <script>alert(1)</script>");
```

Then what doesn't gets executed

```
$("body").html("<iframe> <script>alert(1)</script>");
$("body").html("<iframe><iframe><iframe> <script>alert(1)</script>");
```

In the second example from what works you can see it's not the // which is causing the issue.
So it can be clearly observed in cases which iframe tag is left opened the script doesn't execute.

As I mentioned in the comments before ( I forgot to include it here ), if iframe tag is closed then the script gets executed as it is in the reference of the current page.

Update:

If you run this

```
$("body").html("<iframe> <script>alert(1)</script> ");
```

and check the innerHTML of the iframe, it shows

```
&lt;div&gt;Hi&lt;/div&gt; '&lt;script&gt;alert(1)&lt;/script&gt;'
```

which explains why the script is not getting executed.